# Get age from DOB with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, sql, date, row

I have a database in SQL with name, dob set as a date. I need to display the age of entries to the user.

I have the following

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $row["Name"]. " " .$row["DOB"]. ";
}
```

How can i add a column with the age calucated from the DOB.

Thanks

Comment: sounds more like a "too broad" of a question, iMHo.

Comment: @Fred targeted at the last question, and they've got an answer for their first too!

Comment: @Qirel Agreed; *closed*.

Comment: but how do you do it in a while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$dob = new DateTime($row["DOB"]);
$today   = new DateTime('today');
echo $dob->diff($today)->y . " years old";
```